# The connection to "FILEMAKER: 5003" is not encrypted

Tags: filemaker

I'm using FileMaker Pro 18 Advanced and when I go to Host-> Host Shows I get this error:

```
"The connection to "FILEMAKER: 5003" is not encrypted
This connection is not encrypted and should only be used for test purposes. Do you want to connect anyway?"
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a valid SSL certificate to the server. It will fix this error.
If you don't care about encryption on transit, accept the prompt and connect.